# Can anyone recommend a library with which I can login to a web form, and than execute a javascript function to upload a file?

Tags: java, python

I need to be able to fill out a login form, submit the login information. And then it should upload a file. The catch is that I need to be able to do this at least 100 times concurrently.

I've tried selenium, but selenium gets really slow when you try to start multiple driver.

Comment: I don't think uploading 100 files concurrently will be very fast.

Comment: You could it a headless version. Did you try JMeter ?

Comment: Can't execute the script with JMeter. And I don't need to actually have to complete the uploads. I just want to know what happens when 100+ people try to upload concurrently.

Comment: @Konstantin: Is this for testing a web application? If so, you may want to use a more lightweight library like `requests`. It's very simple to use, but it's not a browser environment.

Comment: @Blender Thanks. I'll try this. I don't need a browser environment. I just need to be able to login to the server, and make an upload request.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you tagged this with Java and Python, I'm assuming your open to using either language.

If you are open to using Python, you could create your own API with [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) and [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to interact with the website and upload the files. Your own creation would allow you to meet your concurrent uploading requirements.

If need be, you could speed up whatever pre-processing you need to do with [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [Numba](https://github.com/numba/numba)

Hope this helps!